# Offscreen Indicator in Unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a 3d game where I'm randomly spawning enemy and from that I want to show enemy's location on screen (arrow mark) like an Indication so that player will able to understand from where every new enemy is coming. [Enemy Indicator Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiXK6.png) as shown in this image exactly same thing I'm trying to achieve. stuck here from long time.

```
        private ECCCar eccCar;
        private GameObject indicator;

        private Vector2 screenLimit;
        private Vector3 copOffset;
        private bool isAboveCop;
        private float cameraPos;
        private float copAxisOffset;
        private float screenAxisLimit;
        private float distToObj;

        private Vector3 toObj;
        private Vector3 axis;
        private float adjacent;
        private float hypotenuous;
        private float theta;
        private float pos;
        private float copPos;

        void Start()
        {
            arrow.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            eccCar = FindObjectOfType<ECCCar>();
            indicator = Instantiate(arrow.gameObject, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

            indicator.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
            screenLimit = DeterminScreenLimit();
        }

        void Update()
        {
            isAboveCop = IsAbove();
            toObj = transform.position - eccCar.transform.position;

            SetAxisHorizontal();
            PerformTrig();

            indicator.transform.position = (Vector3)(eccCar.transform.position) + (toObj.normalized * hypotenuous);
        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            copOffset = DetermineCopOffset();
        }

        private Vector2 DeterminScreenLimit()
        {
            float x = (Camera.main.orthographicSize * Screen.width / Screen.height) - (arrow.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.x / 2);
            float y = (Camera.main.orthographicSize) - (arrow.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.x / 2);

            return new Vector2(x, y);
        }

        private bool IsAbove()
        {
            return transform.position.y > eccCar.transform.position.z ? true : false;
        }

        private Vector2 DetermineCopOffset()
        {
            float x = Camera.main.transform.position.x - eccCar.transform.position.x;
            float z = Camera.main.transform.position.y - eccCar.transform.position.z;

            return new Vector2(x, z);
        }

        private float FindAngleToCorner()
        {
            return Vector2.Angle(CreateVectorToAngle(), Vector2.right);
        }

        private Vector2 CreateVectorToAngle()
        {
            return FindWorldCorner(isAboveCop ? 1 : -1) - (Vector2)eccCar.transform.position;
        }

        private Vector2 FindWorldCorner(int modY)
        {
            float x = Camera.main.transform.position.x + screenLimit.x;
            float y = Camera.main.transform.position.y + (screenLimit.y * modY);

            return new Vector2(x, y);
        }

        private void SetAxisHorizontal()
        {
            axis = Vector2.right;
            pos = transform.position.x;
            copPos = eccCar.transform.position.x;
            cameraPos = Camera.main.transform.position.x;
            copAxisOffset = copOffset.x;
            screenAxisLimit = screenLimit.x;
        }

        private void SetAxisVertical()
        {
            axis = Vector2.up;
            pos = transform.position.y;
            copPos = eccCar.transform.position.z;
            cameraPos = Camera.main.transform.position.y;
            copAxisOffset = copOffset.z;
            screenAxisLimit = screenLimit.y;
        }

        private void PerformTrig()
        {
            FindTheta();
            SetAxis();
            FindAdjacent();
            FindDistToObj();
            ClampAdjacent();
            FindHypotanuous();
        }

        private void FindTheta()
        {
            theta = Vector2.Angle(toObj, axis);

            if(theta > 90)
            {
                theta = 180 - theta;
            }
        }

        private void SetAxis()
        {
            if(theta < FindAngleToCorner())
            {
                SetAxisHorizontal();
            }
            else
            {
                SetAxisVertical();
                FindTheta();
            }
        }

        private void FindAdjacent()
        {
            adjacent = Mathf.Abs(pos - copPos);
        }

        private void FindDistToObj()
        {
            distToObj = pos - cameraPos;
        }

        private void ClampAdjacent()
        {
            if(Mathf.Abs(distToObj) > screenAxisLimit)
            {
                float normalized = distToObj / Mathf.Abs(distToObj);
                adjacent = screenAxisLimit + (copAxisOffset * normalized);

                EnableIndicatorScript(true);
            }
            else
            {
                EnableIndicatorScript(false);
            }
        }

        private void FindHypotanuous()
        {
            theta *= Mathf.Deg2Rad;
            hypotenuous = adjacent / Mathf.Cos(theta);
        }

        private void EnableIndicatorScript(bool show)
        {
            indicator.GetComponent<RectTransform>().gameObject.SetActive(show);
        }

        public void DestroyIndicator()
        {
            Destroy(indicator);
        }
```

Pls help. what is my mistake here I'm not getting because I'm not getting result as per the image I have shown.

Thank You in advance

Comment: Heres another thought.. you can tell if an item is onscreen using isvisible from the renderer, you could setup some colliders just on the edge of your cameras view.. then, raycast, find the hitpoint it hits on the collider, and spawn your markers there..

Comment: Or if you do not wanna deal with colliders or raycast. You can make your map circular and define a radius. Then find direction between enemy and player multiply it with half of the radius, you get the position for indicator. A lot easier in my opinion.

Comment: hey @BugFinder sorry to say but i didn't understand anything actually I'm new on unity so I don't know about raycasting n all ...so if you can able to help me with the same code it will be really helpful for me

Comment: hey @AliKanat thank u so much thats such a great & easy option I'm definitely going to try it today thank you again.